# Which set of preferences for three candidates is impossible?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, puzzle

Hi recently i appeared in an aptitude,there was a problem that i realy cant understand please provide some idea, how to solve it.( sorry to for poor English.)

(Question)-> Three candidates, Amar, Birendra and Chanchal stand for the local election. Opinion polls are conducted and show that fraction a of the voters prefer Amar to Birendra, fraction b prefer Birendra to Chanchal and fraction c prefer Chanchal to Amar. Which of the following is impossible?

```
(a) (a, b, c) = (0.51, 0.51, 0.51);
(b) (a, b, c) = (0.61, 0.71, 0.67);
(c) (a, b, c) = (0.68, 0.68, 0.68);
(d) (a, b, c) = (0.49, 0.49, 0.49);
(e) None of the above.
```

Comment: Preference is not transitive.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Isn't it?

Comment: so what will be ans?

Comment: My answer, because of the term "impossible" would be (e). Real world voting behaviour displays a degree of "irrationality," and it is possible to imagine extreme irrationality.

Comment: Assuming that "undecided" is not an option between any two candidates (which appears to be viable, based on the information at hand), then (d) is impossible if and only if (a) is impossible.

Comment: I think that depends on the questions and how they are evaluated.
I the population sample has to answer the three questions: 'do you prefer A over B', 'do you prefer B over C', do you prefer C over A' then all result are possible. If the probands have to make a ranking like 'I like A most and C least' and this is interpreted as 'A is preferred over B and over C' and 'B is prefered over C' it may be that some results are exluded. Perhaps there are other possibles to pos a question that exclude different results.

Comment: @ all i think d is correct as the below ans suggest because it will never haappen while others may or may not happen so only impossible ans is d :)

Comment: @user2725368: if (d) were impossible then so too would be (a) as Cameron Buie says, as you could simply reverse all preferences.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: If a persons preference is decided by a majority count in a democratic vote of his/her neurons, each neuron having a perticular ranking of the candidats, then indeed the preference of an individual person need not be transitive. I guess though that most people would consider such an opinion embarassing to defend, and would prefer not to pronounce any preference in such a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that people are asked whom they like most and whom they like least of *A*, *B* and *C* and the most liked cannot be the same as the least liked. We have to solve a system of linear equations an inequalities.

We define the three letter variable  as $abc$ the relative frequency that *A* is liked most and *C* is liked least by a person. This should mean *A* is preferred to 
*B* and *C* and *B* to *C*. We now get the folowing four equations:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
abc + acb + cab & = & a \\
bac + bca + abc & = & b \\
cba + cab +bca & = & c \\
abc + acb + bca + bac + cab + cba & = & 1
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The last one means that all frequencies sum up to $1$. 
solving this system of linear equations we can eliminate 4 of the 6 variables and get

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
abc &=& -x-y+b \\
bca &=& x \\
cab &=& y+a+c-1 \\
cba &=& -x-y-a+1 \\
bac &=& y \\
acb &=& x-b-c+1
\end{eqnarray}
$$

(here we introduced the new variable $x$ and $y$ instead of $bca$ and $bac$ to make the notation simpler)
now we know that 
$$0 \le abc \le1, \; 0 \le acb \le 1, \ldots $$

and therefore

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
0 &\le& -x-y+b &\le& 1 \\
0 &\le& x &\le& 1 \\
0 &\le& y+a+c-1 &\le& 1 \\
0 &\le& -x-y-a+1 &\le& 1 \\
0 &\le& y &\le& 1 \\
0 &\le& x-b-c+1 &\le& 1
\end{eqnarray}
$$

from the first and the fourth inequation we get
$$ b-1 \le x+y \le b$$
and
$$ -a \le x+y \le 1-a$$
and therefore
$$\min{\{-a,b-1\}} \le x+y \le \min{\{b,1-a\}}$$

we know that $ 0 \le a$, $b\le 1$, $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$. Therefore
$$0 \le x+y \le \min{\{b,1-a\}} \tag{1}$$
From the for remaining inequalities we get
$$ \max{\{0,c+b-1\}} \le x \le \min{\{1,c+b\}} \tag{2}$$
$$ \max{\{0,1-a-c\}} \le y \le \min{\{1,2-a-c\}} \tag{3}$$

Geometrically each of the inequalities $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ is a stripe in the plane bounded by two parallel lines. In $(1)$ this lines intersect the $x$-axis in $135$ degrees. The left line (lower bound) is through the origin. In $(2)$ the lines are parallel to the $y$-axis and in $(3)$ they are parallel to the $y$-axis. The solution (intersection) of $(2)$ and $(3)$ is a rectangle with sides that are parallel to the axis. This rectangle always lays left from the lower left bound  of the $(1)$-stripe. The stripe and the rectangle have a non-empty intersection if the lower left vertex of the rectangle is in the stripe. This is only the case if it is left  to the right (upper) bound of the stripe.

[image: image of the stripe intersecting the rectangle]
These inequalities have a solution is the sum of the LHS of $(2)$ and $(3)$ is smaller than the RHS of $(1)$ and the sum of the RHS of $(2)$ and $(3)$ is 
larger than the LHS of $(1)$. The latter is always the case so the remaining inequality is

$$\max{\{0,c+b-1\}} + \max{\{0,1-a-c\}} \le \min{\{b,1-a\}} \tag{4}$$

From this it follows that answer $c$ is not possible.

If there is a solution, than there is a solution with 
$$x=\max{\{0,c+b−1\}}$$
$$y=\max{\{0,1−a−c\}}$$
and therefore

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
abc & = & b-\max{\{0 , c+b-1\}}-\max{\{0  , -c-a+1\}} \\
bca & = & \max{\{0 , c+b-1\}} \\ 
cab & = & c+a+\max{\{0 , -c-a+1\}}-1 \\
cba & = & -a- \max{\{0 , c+b-1\}}-\max{\{0 , -c-a+1\}}+1 \\
bac & = & \max{\{0 , -c-a+1\}} \\ 
acb & = & -c-b+ \max{\{0 , c+b-1\}}+1
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I a result contains a negativ component, then no solution exists.
For the frequencies $a$,$b$,$c$ in the OP we get

$$\left[ a=0.51 , b=0.51 , c=0.51 , {\it abc}=0.49 , {\it bca}=0.02
  , {\it cab}=0.02 , {\it cba}=0.47 , {\it bac}=0 , {\it acb}=0.0
  \right] $$

$$\left[ a=0.61 , b=0.71 , c=0.67 , {\it abc}=0.33 , {\it bca}=0.38
  , {\it cab}=0.28 , {\it cba}=0.01 , {\it bac}=0 , {\it acb}=0.0
  \right] $$

$$\left[ a=0.68 , b=0.68 , c=0.68 , {\it abc}=0.32 , {\it bca}=0.36
  , {\it cab}=0.36 , {\it cba}=-0.04 , {\it bac}=0 , {\it acb}=0.0
  \right] $$

$$\left[ a=0.49 , b=0.49 , c=0.49 , {\it abc}=0.47 , {\it bca}=0 , 
 {\it cab}=0.0 , {\it cba}=0.49 , {\it bac}=0.02 , {\it acb}=0.02
  \right] $$

you can check this using

$$a=abc+acb+cab$$
$$b=bca+bac+abc$$
$$c=cab+cba+bca$$

The inequality $(4)$ can be investigated further. We can remove the $\min$ and the $\max$ function by distinguishing 8 different cases. I will not write down this lengthy proof but finally the following holds:

- if two of the sums $a+b$, $a+c$, $b+c$ are $\ge 1$ and one is $\le 1$ than there is a solution for $(4)$
- if two of the sums $a+b$, $a+c$, $b+c$ are $\le 1$ and one is $\ge 1$ than there is a solution for $(4)$
- if all of the three sums $a+b$, $a+c$, $b+c$ are $\le 1$ but $a+b+c \ge 1$ than there is a solution for $(4)$
- if all of the three sums $a+b$, $a+c$, $b+c$ are $\ge 1$ but $a+b+c \le 2$ than there is a solution for $(4)$

This proves the following:

A **necessary** and **sufficient** condition for $(4)$ (and therefore for th OP) to have a solution is that for $a$,$b$ and $c$ holds
$$1 \le a+b+c \le 2$$

Comment: ya in more easy steps if assume that a =1 b is totally independent so it can also be 1 so we assume b=1. so c has no choice because if we chose any person he will also be in a or b so we will get a confliction in vote so all three types have some votes so it will surely less or equal to 2. sorry for poor english

Comment: @user2725368 maybe the picture can clarify the problem

Comment: I think using variables $a,b,c$ **and** three letter variables like $abc,bca$ is a confusing notational convention.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider all six possible orderings (by preference) of the three candidates: $ABC,ACB,BAC,BCA, CAB,CBA$. (Assuming no "ties" occur in the people's opinion).

The question is: Can you assign nonnegative numbers to these six orderings ins such a way that $a=ABC+ACB+CAB$, $b=ABC+BAC+BCA$, and $c=BCA+CAB+CBA$?
For example, we see that $a+b+c=2ABC+ACB+BAC+2BCA+ 2CAB+CBA$, which implies that $1\le a+b+c\le 2$ is a **necessary** condition.

Comment: how this(a+b+c=2ABC+ACB+BAC+2BCA+2CAB+CBA) implies 1≤a+b+c≤2..can you explain plz

Comment: @user2725368 In the answer, at the beginning there is the intention of taking the ABC, ... etc to be the actual counting of the voting. Afterwards, as soon as formulas are written, they actually mean fractions out of all votes. You can imagine then that they are divided by the sum of all $ABC+ACB+BAC+BCA+...$ You get the bound $1$ when all terms with a 2 in front are zero. You get the $2$ bound when all the terms without a 2 are zero.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the reasoning of my other answer I was leaded to the following answer that is much simpler.  It show that the condition stated by @HagenvonEitzen is sufficient bei constructiong explicit solutions.

**Lemma**: $(a,b,c)$ are possible number (as defined in the OP) 
if and only if $0 \le a+b+c \le 1$.

I assume that people are asked whom they like most and whom they like least of *A*, *B* and *C* and the most liked cannot be the same as the least liked. We have to solve a system of linear equations an inequalities.

We define the three letter variable  as $abc$ the relative frequency that *A* is liked most and *C* is liked least by a person. This should mean *A* is preferred to 
*B* and *C* and *B* to *C*.

We now get the folowing four equations:

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
\tag{1}\\
abc + acb + cab & = & a  \\
bac + bca + abc & = & b \\
cba + cab +bca & = & c \\
abc + acb + bca + bac + cab + cba & = & 1
\end{eqnarray}
$$

From this we get
$$a+b+c \\=(abc + acb + cab)+(bac + bca + abc)+(cba + cab +bca)\\=(abc + acb + bca + bac + cab + cba)+(abc+bca+cab)\\=1+(abc+bca+cab)$$
We can conlude that 
$$1 \le a+b+c \le 2 \tag{2}$$
because 
$$0 \le abc+bca+cab \le 1$$

So this is a **necessary** condition for the problem to have a solution.

Now lets assume that
$(2)$ is valid.

Now let's check the three sums $a+b$, $a+c$, $b+c$.
Without loss of generality we assume that $a \le b \le c$ and  therefore $a+b \le a+c \le b+c$.

If all of these sums are $ \le 1$ we set

$$acb=1-b,cba=b+c-1,bac=b+a-1,bca=-b-c-a+2,cab=0,abc=0$$

if all of these sums are $ \ge 1$ we set

$$acb=b+c+a-1,cba=0,bac=0,bca=b,cab=-b-a+1,abc=-b-c+1$$

the remaining case is that at least one sum is $\ge 1$ and at least one sum is $\le 1$. 
So we have $a+b \le 1$ and $b+c \ge 1$. We set

$$acb=a,cba=b+c-1,bac=0,bca=1-c,cab=-b-a+1,abc=0$$

It is easy to check that all these defined values lie between $0$ and $1$. So they are valid relative frequencies.
And they satisfy $(1)$.

So the condition (2) is also **sufficient**.

In your sample only the answer *c* does not fullfill the condition.

Comment: @user2725368 here you find a simple solution for your problem